# Why ES2015 compiling but ES2016 Not?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I am trying simple program to compile using babel + es2015 and es2016 preset + nodejs, problem is ES2016 is not compiling code and show same as created class.

Here is sample code of index.js

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express')
var MyArray = require('./myarray')

const square = new MyArray(10, 10);

console.log(square.area);
```

And this is MyArray.js Class file :

```
class MyArray {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get area() {
    return this.calcArea();
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

When i do compile this using ES2015 then this is result.

```
"use strict";

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

/*
* @Author: Mandeep Singh Gill - thisismyaim@hotmail.com
* @Date:   2016-12-21 17:29:17
* @Last Modified by:   mandeepgill
* @Last Modified time: 2016-12-22 12:07:26
*/

var MyArray = function () {
  function MyArray(height, width) {
    _classCallCheck(this, MyArray);

    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  _createClass(MyArray, [{
    key: "calcArea",
    value: function calcArea() {
      return this.height * this.width;
    }
  }, {
    key: "area",
    get: function get() {
      return this.calcArea();
    }
  }]);

  return MyArray;
}();
```

But when I use ES2016 it displays same MyArray.js code in MyArray Build Directory nothing changed why ?

Comment: `class` is ES2015 ... if you don't have ES2015 preset selected, then the compiler assumes ES2015 is understood by the target so no transpiling required for ES2015 constructs, so use both ES2015 and ES2016 presets

Comment: I am doing like this : ` "presets": ["es2015"]`

Comment: And that one works. Right

Comment: Yes but when in use "presets": ["es2016"] then not working and you said to use "presets": ["es2015", "es2016"] but how this will work ? i think only es2015 will work.

Comment: rather than just saying that you don't think it will work, did you **try** `"presets": ["es2015", "es2016"]` - and read my first comment about WHY? having just es2016 preset means es2015 constructs will be unchanged

Comment: do you also realise that ES2016 gives you two new features ... `Array.prototype.includes` and the `**` operator

Comment: yes i saw and when i use both then it works, yes also i saw new feature, but i want to know using both will not affect my code. Thanks

Comment: using both is a requirement if your target is ES5

Comment: Okay thanks i understand know as es6 not supported by all browsers that's why i am using ES5 complied.